# ¿no se como fijar la jerarquía con unos JFrame? dejo un link a un video explicando el problema

Tags: java, java-swing

He estado investigando mucho en internet y no encuentro ninguna solucion a el problema que tengo con mis ventanas, y como una imagen dice más que mil palabras, les dejo un link a un video que realice donde se ve claramente el problema. 
Me despido agradeciendo por anticipado sus respuestas. Bendiciones.

[Video que muetra el problema en cuestion, haga click aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRwaJseyXzE&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para logar ese comportamiento debes utilizar un `JDialog` en vez de un `JFrame` como tipo de la ventana que abres, ya que el `JFrame` no permite un comportamiento modal. Mira este [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) de Oracle que explica muy bien como hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, pero no funciono lo que sugería. Parece que lo único que queda es hacerlo con foco y threads.

Comment: Si puedes poner el código donde abres la nueva ventana te puedo ayudar mejor

Comment: La respuesta que te da @E.Betanzos es la correcta, no puedes hacer un `JFrame` modal (la modalidad es la forma de ser o de manifestarse una cosa, en esta caso de una ventana), pero **sí** puedes hacer `JDialog` modal, agregando la siguiente línea: `tuDialogo.setModalityType(JDialog.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

Comment: Además, que eso que mencionas de utilizar focos y threads está un poco extraño. Sería bueno saber la razón por la cuál dices que no te funciona con un `JDialog`.

Comment: que es "tuDialogo"?

Comment: Gracias, tenian razon con lo del JDialog se puede  arreglar el problema. Aqui les dejo un enlace donde hay un metodo que me sirvio (el primero)
http://acercadejava.blogspot.cl/2010/07/dialogos-modales-y-no-modales-en-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un enlace que me soluciono el problema, para los que tengan el mismo problema en el futuro y les sirva de ayuda.[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://acercadejava.blogspot.cl/2010/07/dialogos-modales-y-no-modales-en-java.html)

A mi particularmente me sirvio de este modo, sin el nombre Dialog y lo mas importante si el "true" ya que este me bloqueaba unos botones que tenia la ventana

```
  package pruebas;

  import javax.swing.JDialog;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class Modal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame f = new JFrame("");
      f.setSize(300,300);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      JDialog d = new JDialog(f);
      d.setSize(300,300);
      d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      d.setVisible(true);
    }

   }
```